# Sending values to the action script continuously. How to do that?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to repeatedly send values of *username* and *password* to the `php` script. How do I do this ? Like to send the values to the action script, we use `submit` button but how can I send the values automatically to the script and that too continuously ?

```
<form method="post" action="processor.php">
  <input type="username" value="suhail" />
  <input type="password" value="secret_code" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @Florent can you please tell how ?

Comment: One solution is to make an infinite loop with javascript using `setTimeout()`.

Comment: send _from where_?  from a browser?  from a terminal?  why are you trying to do this?  why is no one else suspicious that you're trying to continuously flood a login form?

Comment: @Vucko `setTimeout()` isn't right for infinite loops, you should use `setInterval()` instead.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren why's wrong with using `setTimeout()`? [Works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/7xPN9/)

Comment: @Eevee send from a defined program.Like from a `script`

Comment: so javascript is useless here?  and again, why are you doing this?  this sounds suspiciously like you want to brute-force a password.

Comment: @Vucko Just because something works fine doesn't mean that it's the correct way to do it. For infinitely repeating task such as this they added `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [jQuery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) you can do the following:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('form').ajaxSubmit();
}, 1000);
```

Another solution is to target the form to an iframe so if you submit the form, it doesn't reload the page:

HTML:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="processor.php" target="frm">
  <input type="username" value="suhail" />
  <input type="password" value="secret_code" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<iframe name="frm" id="frm"></iframe>
```

JS:

```
var form = document.getElementById('myform');
setInterval(function() {
    form.submit();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    <script language=javascript>
        var int=self.setInterval(function(){send_data()},1000);
        function send_data()
        {
            document.getElementById('my_form').submit()
        }
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <form method="post" id="my_form" action="processor.php">
      <input type="username" value="suhail" />
      <input type="password" value="secret_code" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="processor.php">
  <input type="username" value="suhail" />
  <input type="password" value="secret_code" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var count=100,i=0;
 for(i=0;i<count;i++) {
  document.getElementById('myform').submit();
 }
</script>
```

This will submit the form 100 times

Comment: It will trigger submit 100 times but most likely there will only be one or two requests this way since the browser will move the user away from the page and stop the script.

Comment: Karl-Johan, Browser will prevent continuous form submit, any way you can set time delay for this submission so that browser will not prevent the submission.

Comment: Not using this method no. Look at the answer provided by @siledh instead, thats the proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax, it's really easy with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). To send the form data to the `processor.php` script:

```
var sendForm = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'processor.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            username: $('#username').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // do something with the answer from server?
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // handle error
        }
    });
}
```

So, `sendForm` is a function that sends the form data to the server. Now, wee need to set a timer that will invoke it repeatedly:

```
window.setInterval(sendForm, 1000); // sends form data every 1000 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You may you $.post or $.get or $.ajax request repeatedly to send continuous request.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var dataString = 'username='+username+"&password="+password;
    $.post('login.php',dataString,function(response){
      //your code what you want to do of response
      alert(response);
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

and html code is like following

```
<form method="post" action="processor.php">
  <input type="username" value="suhail" id="username"/>
  <input type="password" value="secret_code" id="password"/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a full HTML file doing what you want, read the comments.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="processor.php">
  <input type="username" id="username" value="suhail" />
  <input type="password" id="password" value="secret_code" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
function send_request(username, password) {
    var dataString = 'username='+username+"&password="+password;
    $.post('login.php',dataString,function(response){
    // You can check if the login is success/fail here
    console.log(response);

    // Send the request again, this will create an infinity loop
    send_request(username, password);
    });
}

// Start sending request
send_request($('#username').val(), $('#password').val());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var int=self.setInterval(function(){statuscheck()},1000);
function statuscheck()
{
 var username = $("#username").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();

    $.ajax({                                    
        type:"post",
        url:"processor.php",
        dataType: "html",
        cache:false,
        data:"&username="+username+"&password="+password,
        success:function(response){
        alert(response);
    }
    }); 
}
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" action="processor.php">
  <input type="username" value="suhail" id="username"/>
  <input type="password" value="secret_code" id="password"/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```